# How to append the JSON data to HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, codeigniter

I get some data using JSON array. I want to append each data in a div. But I don't get what's wrong in that?

**controller**

```
   function get_performers()
   {
    $id = $this->input->post('id'); 
    $exam = $this->input->post('exam'); 
    $datas=$this->job->get_top_ten_st_data($id,$exam);
    $out['student_details'] = $datas;
     echo json_encode($out); 
   }
```

**script**

```
function get_performers(id,exam)
{

    $.ajax({
        url:"<? echo base_url();?>class_analysis/get_performers", 
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:id,exam:exam},      
        success:function(result) {  
            // alert("haii");
            console.log(result);
            result = JSON.parse(result);

          var tab= "<div class='col-xs-2 blk-ht'>  <span class='hd'>Names</span> </div>";
           for(var i=0;i<result.student_details.length;i++)
            {

                 tab=tab+"<div class='col-ds-1'><span class='subjNames'>" + result.student_details[i]["subject_name"]+ "</span></div> ";
            }   

           jQuery("#subjectNames").append(tab);

        }
    }); 
}
```

Any problem in this?

Comment: what are you expecting to happened what is happening now?

Comment: i want to append the tab to the particular div id

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(result);`?

Comment: In console i got all are null values.Whats wrong in that

Comment: Then you should check the output of your PHP, because the `.ajax` call got `null` from server. I personally use Postman to test my server API..

Answer (score 0):

Try **html** not **append**

```
  jQuery("#subjectNames").html(tab);
```

Also if `jQuery("#subjectNames")` equal with `null` in your console this mean that you don't have element with `id="subjectNames"` in html not `id="#subjectNames"` or other. May be you use classes then try `$(".subjectNames")` with `.` not `#`

Answer (score 0):

The Loop should work... Seems to be another problem with your result.

```js
var tab= "<div class='col-xs-2 blk-ht'><span class='hd'>Names</span> </div>";
for(var i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  tab=tab+"<div class='col-ds-1'><span class='subjNames'>" + "test: " + i + "</span></div> ";
}   
jQuery("#subjectNames").append(tab);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subjectNames"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

dataType: 'json' in $.ajax options - automaticaly parse your json

and USE JQUERY )))

IN SUCCES AJAX FUNCTION

```
$.each( result.student_details, function( key, value ) {
      alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function get_performers()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id'); 
    $exam = $this->input->post('exam'); 
    $datas=$this->job->get_top_ten_st_data($id,$exam);
    $out['student_details'] = $datas;
    echo json_encode($out); 
}
?>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:"<? echo base_url();?>class_analysis/get_performers", 
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    data: {id:id,exam:exam},      
    success:function(result) {

        $.each(response.student_details, function(key,value){
             appendHtml(key,value);
        });


    }
}); 

function appendHtml(key,value)
{
    var tab= "<div class='col-xs-2 blk-ht'>  <span class='hd'>Names</span> </div>";
    tab = tab+"<div class='col-ds-1'><span class='subjNames'>" +value+ "</span></div> ";
    jQuery("#subjectNames").append(tab);
}

</script>
```